# How to automate clicking two buttons on a windows server 2012?

Tags: automation, windows-server-2012

It's really dumb, but I have a program running on a server that crashes every few minutes. In order to restart it I just need to click two buttons.

I tried using actiona to click these two buttons, but everytime I'm no longer remoted into the server actiona stops working. It gave an error "Unable to emulate click; button event failed". It works perfectly though when I have remoted in and I'm observing it.

Is there no screen on a windows server 2012 to click when I'm no longer remoted in? Is there another way I can automate this clicking?

Comment: Can't you end and program and restart it using cmd or PowerShell?

Comment: See if the free AutoIT software and using the [ControlClick()](https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/ControlClick.htm) helps and can do this. I did something similar in the past for a company but I no longer support this system nor have access to confirm if it works via disconnected RDP session but maybe worth a try.

Comment: @DxTx, not that I know of. Even if i start the program through cmd by running the exe, I still have to click a button on the GUI. I don't think there's a command that I can do for that step.